# Increase size of Twemoji in REACT

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

My REACT component's code is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Twemoji } from 'react-emoji-render';
import emoji.css;


const emoji = () => {
    return ( <Twemoji className="Twemoji" text=":+1:"/> );
}

export default emoji;
```

My css file (emoji.css) has the following code

```
.Twemoji {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
}

but the size of the emoji doesn't change. 

if I inspect the element and modify the inline style in the page html that works 
Please can you help me understand how I can increase the emoji size via CSS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twemoji Component does not take a prop className ([see here](https://github.com/tommoor/react-emoji-render/blob/09110cfabcfcb84022deba6aa8cb930a8af32f28/src/index.js#L29)), instead you will have to use the options prop in order to pass a custom css classname

```
const options = { className: "Twemoji" };
const emoji = () => {
    return ( <Twemoji text=":+1:" options={options} /> );
}
```

EDIT:

you would also have to add `!important` to `width` and `height` in the css class to take precedence over the element style ([see css precedence](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/))

```
.Twemoji {
width: 4em !important;
height: 4em !important;
}
```

Comment: tried your solution but didn't work well in my application, still the same size. Does it work for you?

Comment: sorry, I actually did not test it before. you still have to add !important to your css properties to override the default styles.